# linq to sql query interceptor

Tags: linq-to-sql, interceptor

I'm looking at implementing some LINQ to SQL but am struggling to see how we woudl add in access control business rules such as customer a can only view their orders.
In ado.net data services, query intercptors do exactly what I am after, and can see how to check on update / insert / delete, but is there an equivalent of this:

```
[QueryInterceptor("Orders")] 
public IQueryable<Orders> OnQueryOrders(IQueryable<Orders> orderQuery) 
{ 

      return from o in orderQuery 
         where o.Customers.ContactName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name 
         select o; 
}
```

Or wil I need to control via accessors along the line of:
    GetOrdersByCustomer(string customerId)

Comment: Personally, I find something like GetOrdersByCustomer much easier to understand and maintain.  Interceptors feel like unnecessary complexity here.  Think about the next person who will have to maintain your code and who may not be as smart as you are.

Comment: That would be fine for simple scenarios, but I want to allow much richer query building so woudl end up aith upwards of 100 accessors very quickly which in turn would be confusing/error proe/nightmare to maintain or refactor.  While interceptors can be confusing, they do allow for key code concerns to run consistenly - but think that Justins thoughts are closer to what we will end up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in this case, the better solution would be to build a true Business Layer that sits between the Application Layer and your LINQ to SQL classes.

You would then query your Business Layer, which in turn would implement all your Business Logic and filtering. If architected properly, that Business Layer could be fairly transparent to anybody coding the Application Layer and then everybody would be happy.

Comment: Hi Justin
Yes, that is looking like the route I will have to take.
My approach looks like it will be:
make my dataContext sealed, but my data objects public (ie tables in linq to sql) 
Expose methods out from BL which can take in predicate functions which will then get added to an expression tree with business security logic.  In my prototypes this is working and while a little confusing initially, what is exposed is pretty clear but flexible.

Comment: Depending on the scope and nature of the application, creating a entire BL may not be practical. LINQ to SQL is capable of handling business rules validation all on its own. You can use partial classes to "intercept" data operations achieving a similar goal as with ADO.NET query interceptors. Check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882671.aspx